# Недостаток в переводе на главной странице

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Обнаружен недостаток в переводе.

На главной странице указатель на количество новых вопросов / вопросов с изменениями гласит:

> 2 вопросов с новыми действиями

Очевидно, что правильно было бы сказать:

> 2 вопроса с новыми действиями

---

[image: баннер с новой активностью]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это была ошибка в переводе. Исправил. Со следующим обновлением строк исправление будет выкачено на сайт.

Спасибо, что сообщили!